# Calculating economic scope

Tags: industrial-organisation

The costs of running a university are $C = F + m_{1}*q_{1} + m_{1}*q_{1}^{2} + m_{2}*q_{2} + m_{2}*q_{2}^{2}$ where $ q_{1} $ is the number of students taking courses during the academic year and $q_{2}$ is the number of student taking summer courses. How large are the economies of scope that result from offering courses throughout the year, and how do they vary with the number of either type of students?

This is a question in a old exam I am trying to understand, I have no solution or answer. I only know about this way for economical scope $\frac{ C(Q_{1}, 0) + C(0, Q_{2}) - C(Q_{1}, Q_{2}) }       {    C(Q_{1}, Q_{2})    } > 0$ , which I dont know if could be used for this question, or how to use it in this question.

Comment: Forgot to put $F$ in the cost function, now it is there

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the questioner has shown no effort. (For example I see no effort to determine how economies of scope could be measured.)